# RxJS6 (angular 6) - ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I recently update my application to angular 6 as well as the RxJs to `6.3.3` `version`.

As described in [here](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/), I used the package `rxjs-compat` to have temporarily the code written in RxJS5 and RxJS6 compatibility mode, at the same time.

As suggested by the RxJS team, after I update all my code to be compatible with RxJS6, I uninstalled the `rxjs-compat` because it is not longer necessary.

After that, I'm trying to run my code but the compiler is retrieving the following error:

> ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'rxjs-compat'

Any one know what can be the problem in here? This seems that the RxJS pacadge depends on `rxjs-compat`, but if what I'm saying is true, why the RxJS team recommends to uninstall `rxjs-compat`?

Comment: remove the package from package json

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka which package?

Comment: It looks like you're somewhere trying to import from `rxjs/Rx` that was possible only in older RxJS versions and isn't possible with RxJS 6. The `rxjs-compat` package emulates this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some search I found out [this post](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3764#issuecomment-393456370) that advice to search in all of my code and remove all imports that referenced the `rxjs/Rx`:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx'
```

After I remove this import in all places of my code, the error disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try this

```js
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Comment: after uninstalling rxjs-compat, he is facing this issue. It is recommended to uninstall rxjs-compat after migrating old code to new syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This module ensures backward compatibility when you migrate from rxjs-5 to rxjs-6.

You can find more information about rxjs-compat in [an article by Nicholas Jamieson on Medium](https://medium.com/@cartant/rxjs-avoiding-rxjs-compat-4b79a566359b). It describes when you need this module and when you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

installing rxjs-compact solved it for me

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat'.
```

the solution is simple you just have to run the following command.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the core issue, which is that it shouldn't be needed at all.